# Open IE with a command line arguement

Tags: .net, internet-explorer

I need to write a console app to open an instance of Internet Explorer. That part is simple.

But I am having a hard time finding out a way to do so with some command line arguments.

Specifically, I need to open IE with the -noframemerging option from a console app.

Any ideas or pointers?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

P.S. If any one knows a way to fire up other browsers in a new Session, I am open to those answers/responses as well.

Just to clarify, I need to open IE (or other browsers as a bonus) in a "New Session".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
//system.diagnostics
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "IEXPLORE.EXE",
    Arguments = "-noframemerging http://www.google.com"
};
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: That works Alex, thank you very much!! I owe you a beer. Do you know if there is anyway to control properties of IE with the process object, like you can with "SHDocVw.InternetExplorer" (e.g.: no toolbar, no address bar, etc.)?

Comment: Not elegantly or reliably afaik (You can wait and scan open shell windows for an hwnd matching the process's main window handle)

Comment: If you want no toolbars/menu you could just stick a webbrowser control on a windows form and make your own browser exe, iirc they always run in their own "session"

Comment: Internet Explorer only supports launching in "Kiosk mode" from the command line (-k). You can't control other features.

Comment: @ErikLaw, this is incorrect information. Using Alex's solution, I am able to use all of the available command line arguments, including the one he suggested which is the one I need. If I use "SHDocVw.InternetExplorer", I can control all aspects of the browser but can't figure out how to use any of the command line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up with so far (Thanks Alex!!):

```
Dim url As String = "http://www.mysite.com"
Dim cmdLineOptions As String = "-noframemerging"
Dim args As String = String.Format("{0} {1}", cmdLineOptions, url)

Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo() With {
    .FileName = "IEXPLORE.EXE",
    .Arguments = args
}

Process.Start(startInfo)
```

Just need to know how to control some IE options (no menu, no tool bar, etc) in addition to the above, which I don't know if it can be done using the "Process" or "ProcessStartInfo" objects.